# Series and probability

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

**The task at hand:**

Suppose there are 3 players (A,B,C), who have 3 different dices with the following chances (per roll) to win:

Player A has a dice with a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance to win

Player B has a dice with a $\frac{2}{5}$ chance to win

Player C has a dice with a $\frac{4}{7}$ chance to win

Player A starts rolling the dice, followed by Player B, then C and then starting with A all over again until one player wins.

Calculate the chance of player A to win.

My question is wether the following approach is valid or has a logical error:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{5}\frac{3}{7})^n(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{2\cdot3\cdot3}{3\cdot5\cdot7})^n= \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{18}{105})^n= \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{18}{105})}= \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{(\frac{87}{105})} =\frac{105}{261} \sim 0.4023$

Comment: This is not clear.  Chances of what?  To be precise...what specific event is, say, $p_A$ the probability of?

Comment: Sry, was indeed unprecise, is it understandable now?

Comment: Does the game stop when one player rolls a win?

Comment: @grixor yes, it does

Comment: I kept thinking there's no way your method could be correct because it is less than $\frac{1}3{}$ but then I saw what I think is an error in the last step of your calculation.

Comment: Your solution is correct. It's the same idea as the geometric distribution.

Comment: @turkeyhundt indeed, it should be $\frac{105}{261} \sim 0.4022988505747126$ if im not mistaken

Comment: @Evan Aad Thanks for validating

Comment: Still don't get it.  Those three probabilities do not add to $1$ ...   $\frac 13+\frac 25+\frac 47=1.304761905$.

Comment: Oh...are you saying, "first $A$ rolls...and either wins or doesn't.  If $A$ does not win, then $B$ gets to try, and so on cyclically until we have a winner at which point the game ends."  If that's what you mean, it makes sense.

Comment: @lulu yes exactly

Comment: I'll post an alternate method.

Answer (score 1):

Best, I think, to work "recursively".

Define:  If $X,Y\in \{A,B,C\}$, not necessarily distinct,  then $P(X,Y)$ denotes the probability that $X$ will eventually win given that $Y$ is starting.  Thus the answer you seek is $P(A,A)$.

As is standard, we will also let $q_X=1-p_X$ for $X\in \{A,B,C\}$

Consider the first roll.  $A$ wins or she doesn't.  This implies that $$P(A,A)=p_A\times 1+q_A\times P(A,B)$$

Similarly:
$$P(A,B)=p_B\times 0+q_B\times P(A,C)\quad \&\quad P(A,C)=p_C\times 0+q_C\times P(A,A)$$

Easy to see that this implies that $$P(A,A)=\frac {p_A}{1-q_Aq_Bq_C}$$

Using your numbers we confirm that $P(A,A)=\fbox {0.402298851}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the probability that A wins. So $x$ equals P(A rolls a win) + P(B does not roll a win and C does not roll a win)*$x$. In other words:$$x = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{5}\frac{3}{7}x$$
and so 
$$x = \frac{35}{3*29} \approx 0.4023.$$